# HTML to PDF with Node.js and Electron.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, electron, html-pdf

> Here are the relevant code.

```
        let Name = moment().unix() + ".pdf";
        var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
        let filename = "C:\\App\\Register\\pdf\\" + Name;
        pdf.create(html, options).toFile(filename, function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
             res.status(403).json({
               message: 'error'
             })
           } else {
              res.status(200).json({
               message: 'success'
             })

           }
    }
```

> it's working fine on dev version and create PDF file. But when i create a
>   electron build-pack, the pdf file not generated.

If any solution is available then it will be a big help

Comment: any errors to console?

Comment: No.. I working and generate PDF file on development version but when i run build-pack .exe file then the PDF file not generated, and there is no any console on build-pack version.

Comment: what do you get if you add `console.log(err, response)` juste after the `pdf.create()` line ?

Comment: console is not running on electron-build version.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an absolute path for packaged application by using [app.getAppPath()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath).

Remplace this line

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
```

By this

```
var html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(app.getAppPath(), '/test/businesscard.html', 'utf8'));
```

And not forgot to add

```
const path = require('path')
const app = require('electron').remote.app
```

Comment: i already try to solve to place html in the same block of code before the pdf.create(html, options) but still the same error..